# Program to find the factorial of number and to give error message for negative integer input

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I'm learning C++ and am trying create a program to find the factorial of a positive integer. I've been able to find the factorial of a positive integer. However, I am still trying to have the program give an error message when the input is not a positive integer. So far, the error message has been combined with the standard output message.

How do I construct loops such that the factorial of the given positive integer is found for a positive integer input, while providing only an error message when the input is not a positive integer? Code is below. Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int i;
    int n;
    int factorial;

    factorial = 1;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer. This application will find its factorial." << '\n';
    cin >> i;

    if (i < 1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a positive integer" << endl;
        break;
    }

    else
        for (n = 1; n <= i; ++n)
        {
            factorial *= n;
        }

    cout << " Factorial " << i << " is " << factorial << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `break;` will exit a brace-enclosed section of a loop or switch. As the last line in an `if` it does nothing.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can only handle factorials up to 12 (32 bit `int`) or 20 (64 bit `int`) before `factorial` overflows and gives the wrong result. You may want to look into Big Integer libraries to handle larger factorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check if your factorial function returns the correct results. Also, you may wish to make it recursive, :)

Add braces for your `else`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int i;
    int n;
    int factorial;

    factorial = 1;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer. This application will find its factorial." << '\n';
    cin >> i;

    if (i < 1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a positive integer" << endl;
        break;
    }

    else {
        for (n = 1; n <= i; ++n)
        {
            factorial *= n;
        }
        cout << " Factorial " << i << " is " << factorial << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete factorial of number program of c++ which handles positive, negative numbers and also zero.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
i

nt main()
{
    int number,factorial=1;
    cout<<"Enter Number to find its Factorial: ";
    cin>>number;
    if(number<0)
    {
        cout<<"Not Defined.";
    }
    else if (number==0)
    {
        cout<<"The Facorial of 0 is 1.";
    }
    else
    {
      for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)
      {
          factorial=factorial*i;
      }
    cout<<"The Facorial of "<<number<<" is "<<factorial<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can read complete code explanation on http://www.cppbeginner.com/numbers/how-to-find-factorial-of-number-in-cpp/